# Only root can login. Possible reasons?

Tags: linux, embedded, arm

I have a FriendlyARM Mini2440 ARM board and I've used `multistrap` to create a base debian 6.0 root fs for it. Kernel is the official linux-2.6.32.2 tree from FriendlyARM website. everything works great except only root can login. other users also successfully login but instantly get logged out and it never gets to shell prompt. I can't find why.

Maybe serial terminal device permissions? `/dev/s3c2410_serial0` which is the serial terminal device file, belongs to `root:tty` and has 600 permission, but the permission can not be modified even with udev rules.

any thoughts?

Edit: this is `/etc/passwd`

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/bin/sh
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/bin/sh
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/bin/sh
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/bin/sh
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/bin/sh
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/bin/sh
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/bin/sh
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/bin/sh
libuuid:x:100:101::/var/lib/libuuid:/bin/sh
ntp:x:101:102::/home/ntp:/bin/false
dnsmasq:x:102:65534:dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/misc:/bin/false
stunnel4:x:103:105::/var/run/stunnel4:/bin/false
sshd:x:104:65534::/var/run/sshd:/usr/sbin/nologin
op:x:1000:1000:,,,:/home/op:/bin/bash
op2:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/op2:/bin/bash
```

`op` and `op2` are user accounts i created by `adduser` command.

I also added these users to `root`, `tty`, `dialout`, `users` and `ssh` groups, but still no luck.

From both ssh and serial terminal, `op` user successfully logs in, `/etc/motd` is printed, "Last login " line is printed, and then it cleanly exits.

SOLVED (kind of)

sorry, I found it. I had changed `vm.mmap_min_addr` kernel variable from default value of 4096 to 65536. I read somewhere that this is a good idea from a security standpoint, but didn't knew it could break some processes.

Kernel documentation says (just for reference):

`mmap_min_addr`

> This file indicates the amount of address space  which a user process will
> be restricted from mmaping.  Since kernel null dereference bugs could
> accidentally operate based on the information in the first couple of pages
> of memory userspace processes should not be allowed to write to them.  By
> default this value is set to 0 and no protections will be enforced by the
> security module.  Setting this value to something like 64k will allow the
> vast majority of applications to work correctly and provide defense in depth
> against future potential kernel bugs.

But I'm still not sure why everything else worked, except non-root user login.

Comment: What's `/etc/passwd` look like? Does the user's shell exist?

Comment: I had this problem too on an armel installation: mmap_min_addr is set to 4096 by default in Debian 6 which somehow made all my non-root processes crash immediately. The result of course was the immediate log-out again after logging in (even when started via "su"). Setting mmap_min_addr to 0 ("off"), solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the shell used for the other accounts ? Grep your username in `/etc/passwd` and check if you have the full path of a shell in the last field.
If you want to change, you would like to try the `chsh` command.

Could you try also to login from root by typing for example :

```
# su - youruser -c /bin/bash
```

Comment: I tried this command. it immediately returns back to my root prompt.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a `/etc/nologin`? If so, simply delete it. This file prevents non-root-users to login.

Comment: no, there is no `/etc/nologin`